# A six-year-old boy or A six-years-old boy?

Tags: articles

Which one is correct?

> 1. A six-year-old boy
> 2. A six-years-old boy

I see both usage when I search in google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say the first one is correct. We say:

*The boy is six years old*, but *He is a six-year-old boy*.

*The snake is five meters long*, but *It is a five-meter-long snake.*

*The pool is twenty feet wide*, but *It is a twenty-foot-wide pool*.

You need to drop the plural to form the adjective.

[This page](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/adj_numbermodifiers.html) has more information and examples on the same.